# JDBC in groovy script mysql access denied even though permissions are set up correctly

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, groovy

I have written the following groovy script to connect to a mysql database:

```
this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new File("/root/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar").toURL())

import groovy.sql.*

def username = 'root'
def password = 'password'
def database = 'database'
def server = 'localhost'

def db = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://$server/$database", "$username", "$password", 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
```

When i run it like this:

```
groovy sqlcon.groovy
```

I get the following error:

> Caught: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>           at query.run(query.groovy:10)

But I can log in to the mysql database locally using the same credentials and the output from

```
SELECT Host, User FROM mysql.user;
```

looks like this:

```
+-----------+------------------+
| Host      | User             |
+-----------+------------------+
| 127.0.0.1 | root             |
| localhost | root             |
+-----------+------------------+
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this behaviour ?
Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you may need to specify your mysql port for the connection.

Try this:

```
def username = 'root'
def password = 'password'
def database = 'database'
def server = 'localhost:3306'

def db = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://$server/$database", "$username", "$password", 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
```